# Better text in SVG announcements in screen readers (VoiceOver)

Tags: svg, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I have an SVG figure that represents a name card for a person:

```html
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 300 100"
    style="border: 1px solid black;"
  >
    <g>
      <text x="5" y="25">Name</text>
      <text x="120" y="25">Joe Smith</text>
    </g>

    <g>
      <text x="5" y="55">Age</text>
      <text x="120" y="55">55</text>
    </g>

    <g>
        <text x="5" y="85">Occupation</text>
        <text x="120" y="85">Astronaut</text>
      </g>
  </svg>
```

VoiceOver reads it like this:

> Name, group
>
> Name
>
> End of, name, group
>
> Joe Smith, group
>
> Joe Smith
>
> End of, Joe Smith, group
>
> Age, group
>
> Age
>
> End of, Age, group
>
> 55, group
>
> 55
>
> End of, 55, group
>
> Occupation, group
>
> Occupation
>
> End of, Occupation, group
>
> Astronaut, group
>
> Astronaut
>
> End of, Astronaut, group

It's very, very verbose. How do I modify this code to make VoiceOver read it like this?

> Name
>
> Joe Smith
>
> Age
>
> 55
>
> Occupation
>
> Astronaut

I'm looking for a solution using SVG / ARIA. I know I can implement this using HTML and achieve better results in VoiceOver, but this is just a dummy example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove the `<g>` elements as they serve no real purpose for display (they are used for layering in an editor and as a possible point to apply transforms, styling etc.)

After doing that the element will read correctly.

I recommend using [SVG OMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to optimise your SVGs, especially if they are large and complex graphics. You may still need to remove some `<g>` tags, you can safely do this just using a replace function on `<g>` and `</g>` (the hacky way!) or better yet use an XML reader / writer and do it properly!

Comment: I just removed all three `<g>`'s and tested in Safari + VO, and groups are still being announced. So it's not a solution unfortunately. Also, for a more complex SVG, I might want `<g>`'s anyway things like positioning.

Comment: `<g>` dictates groups, clear your cache as there is definitely no way for the SVG to announce groups if you remove the `<g>` and closing `</g>`. `<g>` elements do not dictate positioning, that is the x="5" y="85" parts of each text item. (you can use `<g>` for things like styling and rotation)

Comment: One thing I can suggest (but I haven't tried as I always remove the `<g>` elements and style using classes) is using `<title>` and `<desc>` - not sure if it overrides the text within the SVG. Final though is to use `aria-labelledby` and create a label containing the info, that may also override.

Comment: If you look at how VO announces that SVG, you'll see that it announced a group for each `<text>`, not each `<g>`. It's not a cache issue (and I was using a local `.html` file to test anyway). It just seems that VO doesn't announce `<g>`'s at all so removing them didn't have any impact.

Comment: I use `<g>`' often for positioning. Like `<g transform="translate(x, y)">`. That allows me to use a different coordinates within a `<g>`. Anyway, as per previous comment, I don't think `<g>`'s are being announced anyway.

Comment: try `aria-labelledby`, I have never come across the issue with SVGs I have created where it announces `<text>` as groups, I wonder if there is a verbosity setting somewhere in VO you have turned all the way up. I will try and test later for you.

Comment: final thought - have you defined your SVG with the two main parameters `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 376 92">` as that may be an issue (yet again I always do it so not sure if it matters to have the `xmlns` to inform the screen reader how to interpret the information? Obviously valid HTML5 without it but just trying to think why you would see a different experience than me)

Comment: Nice spot, but unfortunately worked the same with `xmlns` and without `<g>`'s.